# What is the quick fix for CSRF attack?

Tags: web-application, appsec, csrf, threat-mitigation

The application is constructed in Java language and JSF framework. I have reported a CSRF attack and the development team have to fix it soon since the application is in production.

I recommended to use CSRF tokens but the development team says it may take some time for the implementation.

Can any of you suggest a better and faster way to remediate CSRF? If it is a temporary solution for now, that is also fine. Later, they will implement the proper CSRF tokens in the code in a reasonable time.

Comment: just require POST, then it can basically only work w/XSS, which is it's own issue anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick fix against CSRF is to check the `Referer` and/or `Origin` HTTP header. At least one of these should be set and the domain it contains should be your domain (i.e. same origin).

Note that this will break cases where your site is accessed from a bookmark, link inside a mail or similar since in thus cases no `Referer` will be sent. But in no case you should simply accept an empty `Referer` (unless you have a non-empty `Origin` header) since this is easy to create for an attacker.

You should also make sure that your checks for the domain are correct. This is, if your site is `www.example.com` you must not accept `Referer` like `http://www.example.com.attacker.com` or `http://www.attacker.com/www.example.com` or `http://www-example.com`.

You should also make sure that the attacker can not use other functionality (or bugs) in your application as a trampoline to create a custom request with malicious payload but the expected same-origin `Referer`. As [Arminius](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/95381/arminius) nicely pointed out in a comment, open redirects might be such a trampoline. Thus you should either make sure that all requests to the domain have a same-origin `Referer` or that any parts which might need to accept a cross-origin `Referer` can not be abused as trampoline.

For more information about this method of protecting against CSRF and about its potential problems see [Verifying Same Origin with Standard Headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Verifying_Same_Origin_with_Standard_Headers) in the [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) from OWASP.

Comment: However, Firefox currently doesn't send the `Origin` header by default, and checking the `Referer` alone isn't always sufficient since other features such as open redirects may allow an attacker to forge the header. But as a quick fix it may definitely help.

Comment: @Arminius: thanks for pointing out the danger of open redirects. I've integrated it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use Same Site cookies (`SameSite=Strict;`). Essentially this attribute, when enabled, prevents the browser from sending cookies from cross-site requests. This could potentially break some functionality, however it's another idea that could be added quickly:

https://medium.com/compass-security/samesite-cookie-attribute-33b3bfeaeb95

Downfall - not all browsers support it.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to mitigate this vulnerability is a [synchronizer token pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens). Only with a token.

Try to use [OWASP CSRFGuard project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CSRFGuard_Project)

Comment: I added links to the things you were talking about, and the OWASP page defines the ***2*** methods, not just tokens. The OP already stated that tokens are not possible, which means the other methods are worthy of mention.